# Android intent filter based on sdk version

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm writing an Android app that the minSdkVersion is 7, but there are some features that needs sdk version 8.

I also have some intents that i can resolve, but one of those intents is using features of sdk version 8, which means that i would like to filter that intent based on the user sdk version. Can it be done?

My solution for now (It is not a very good one) is that i accept this intent from all versions and in case that the sdk version is 7 I call the same intent again.

I really hope that some one have a real solution or at least a better one.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use this to get sdk version Build.VERSION.SDK_INT and then modify ur code accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you meant.
If your solution is to do so during run time, that means that I already got the intent and in case that the SDK is lower I cannot really do anything with it except from launching the same intent again (which can result an infinite loop).

Can you please elaborate your solution?